Interpreting xdata and pdata section to hand write RUNTIME_FUNCTION and UNWIND_INFO for RtlAddFunctionTable
I am trying to inject some assembly code at runtime to circumvent a restriction in my language's runtime (VBA). I was originally writing assembly by hand compiling with flat assembler fasm, but found out I need to include exception handling info (unwind codes msdn) which look too fiddly to do by hand, so I've switched to writing code in C and compiling that to get my assembly code. I then inject the code using VirtualAlloc to get an executable region for the machine code and invoke the function pointer.
Now I am trying to figure out how to register the unwind info with RtlAddFunctionTable. I know it is held in the xdata and pdata sections of my compiled c code, although as I say I can't rely on those since the code is runtime injected. Here is the extract from listing.cod
I have this xdata
xdata   SEGMENT
$unwind$Release DD 020601H
    DD  030023206H
xdata   ENDS

although in dumpbin.exe it looks like it is set out in reverse order
RAW DATA #4
  00000000: 01 06 02 00 06 32 02 30                          .....2.0

And this pdata
pdata   SEGMENT
$pdata$Release DD imagerel $LN6
    DD  imagerel $LN6+54
    DD  imagerel $unwind$Release
pdata   ENDS

(where $LN6 is the first line of executable TEXT section). The pdata can also be viewed with dumpbin as
RAW DATA #5
  00000000: 00 00 00 00 36 00 00 00 00 00 00 00              ....6.......

Function Table #5 (1)

           Begin     End       Info

  00000000 00000000  00000036  00000000

RELOCATIONS #5
                                                Symbol    Symbol
 Offset    Type              Applied To         Index     Name
 --------  ----------------  -----------------  --------  ------
 00000000  ADDR32NB                   00000000         A  $LN6
 00000004  ADDR32NB                   00000036         A  $LN6
 00000008  ADDR32NB                   00000000         D  $unwind$Release

And I am expecting that to correspond to RUNTIME_FUNCTION:



Size
Value




ULONG
Function start address


ULONG
Function end address


ULONG
Unwind info address



And UNWIND_INFO



Size
Value




UBYTE: 3
Version


UBYTE: 5
Flags


UBYTE
Size of prolog


UBYTE
Count of unwind codes


UBYTE: 4
Frame Register


UBYTE: 4
Frame Register offset (scaled)


USHORT * n
Unwind codes array


variable
Can either be of form (1) or (2) below



How do I interpret the pdata and xdata to get these?

My attempt
From the xdata 01 06 02 00 06 32 02 30  we get the UNWIND_INFO, I'm really not sure about the mapping. I think the function prologue length is 0x06.
$LN6:
  00000 40 53        push    rbx
  00002 48 83 ec 20  sub     rsp, 32            ; 00000020H

Let's say I VirtualAlloc the UNWIND_INFO at 0x1122334411223344 and the executable code at0x1122334455667788 for the base address of my function, then I think the RUNTIME_FUNCTION is



Size
Definition
Value




ULONG
Function start address
0x1122334455667788


ULONG
Function end address
0x1122334455667788 + 0x36 ($LN6+54 from pdata)


ULONG
Unwind info address
0x1122334411223344



However these are ULONG not ULONGLONG so I guess they must be relative offsets {0x00000000, 0x00000036, ??? } and that the unwind info must be contiguous to guarantee a ULONG sized offset?
Additional Context
For further info this is the C code I'm trying to inject
#include <OAIdl.h>
#include <objbase.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <windows.h>

typedef struct {
    void *pVTable;
    ULONG refCount;
    IUnknown *comObject; // Using IUnknown pointer from Windows headers
} MyStruct;

// Placeholder address cast to function pointer matching CoTaskMemFree signature
typedef void(__stdcall *CoTaskMemFreeType)(void *pv);

ULONG Release(MyStruct **pthis) {
    // Prologue should set base pointer for easy stack unwinding, and also
    // allocate the shadow space expect to see adjustment = 32 bytes (0x20):
    //  0x20 for 4 8-byte shadow space to make Call
    //  and no misalignment since push rbx + return address keep everything 16 byte aligned
    MyStruct *this = *pthis;
    this->refCount--;
    if (this->refCount == 0) {
        if (this->comObject != NULL) {
            this->comObject->lpVtbl->Release(this->comObject);
        }
        // Call the placeholder CoTaskMemFree function
        ((CoTaskMemFreeType)0x8877665544332211)(this);
    }
    return this->refCount;
    // Epilogue restores rbp to pop stack frame and deallocates shadow stack space by restoring rsp
}

compiled with
cl.exe /options:strict /nologo /FAcs /c /W4 /Fa'.\build\listing' /Fo'.\build\compiled' -O1 '.\object_release.c'

to give listing.cod
; Listing generated by Microsoft (R) Optimizing Compiler Version 19.40.33812.0 

include listing.inc

INCLUDELIB LIBCMT
INCLUDELIB OLDNAMES

PUBLIC  Release
;   COMDAT pdata
pdata   SEGMENT
$pdata$Release DD imagerel $LN6
    DD  imagerel $LN6+54
    DD  imagerel $unwind$Release
pdata   ENDS
;   COMDAT xdata
xdata   SEGMENT
$unwind$Release DD 020601H
    DD  030023206H
xdata   ENDS
; Function compile flags: /Ogspy
; File C:\Users\xxx\Documents\GitHub\VBA-IterableFramework\Machine Code\object_release.c
;   COMDAT Release
_TEXT   SEGMENT
pthis$ = 48
Release PROC                        ; COMDAT

; 16   : ULONG Release(MyStruct **pthis) {

$LN6:
  00000 40 53        push    rbx
  00002 48 83 ec 20  sub     rsp, 32            ; 00000020H

; 17   :     // Prologue should set base pointer for easy stack unwinding, and also
; 18   :     // allocate the shadow space expect to see adjustment = 32 bytes (0x20):
; 19   :     //  0x20 for 4 8-byte shadow space to make Call
; 20   :    //  and no misalignment since push rbx + return address keep everything 16 byte aligned
; 21   :     MyStruct *this = *pthis;

  00006 48 8b 19     mov     rbx, QWORD PTR [rcx]

; 22   :     this->refCount--;

  00009 83 6b 08 01  sub     DWORD PTR [rbx+8], 1

; 23   :     if (this->refCount == 0) {

  0000d 75 1e        jne     SHORT $LN2@Release

; 24   :         if (this->comObject != NULL) {

  0000f 48 8b 4b 10  mov     rcx, QWORD PTR [rbx+16]
  00013 48 85 c9     test    rcx, rcx
  00016 74 06        je  SHORT $LN3@Release

; 25   :             this->comObject->lpVtbl->Release(this->comObject);

  00018 48 8b 01     mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rcx]
  0001b ff 50 10     call    QWORD PTR [rax+16]
$LN3@Release:

; 26   :         }
; 27   :         // Call the placeholder CoTaskMemFree function
; 28   :         ((CoTaskMemFreeType)0x8877665544332211)(this);

  0001e 48 8b cb     mov     rcx, rbx
  00021 48 b8 11 22 33
    44 55 66 77 88   mov     rax, -8613303245920329199 ; 8877665544332211H
  0002b ff d0        call    rax
$LN2@Release:

; 29   :     }
; 30   :     return this->refCount;

  0002d 8b 43 08     mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbx+8]

; 31   :     // Epilogue restores rbp to pop stack frame and deallocates stack space
; 32   : }

  00030 48 83 c4 20  add     rsp, 32            ; 00000020H
  00034 5b       pop     rbx
  00035 c3       ret     0
Release ENDP
_TEXT   ENDS
END

